# Generate the worst case 256-bit input for GCD

Tags: complex-analysis, gcd-and-lcm, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a fast method for generating the worst case 256-bit input for GCD?

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency), the worst case for GCD is when the inputs are consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

However, how exactly can I find the largest pair of consecutive Fibonacci numbers which are at most $2^{256}-1$?

Thank you!

Comment: There's a closed form formula for the Fibonacci numbers, so it shouldn't be too difficult to find the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Fibonacci numbers have a [closed form formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression):

$$
F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right).
$$

Since $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}>1$ and $\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right|<1$, for large $n$,
$$
F_n\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.
$$

Now, you can take a logarithm to estimate the value of $n$.  In particular, we want
$$
n\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\ln\sqrt{5}<256\ln 2.
$$
Solving for $n$, we get
$$
n<370.41...
$$

Therefore, the largest Fibonacci number would be $F_{370}$.  You can then estimate this with the closed form formula or its approximation (the correction term is on the order of $10^{-78}$).

Answer (score 2):

$$ F_{370} =  94611056096305838013295371573764256526437182762229865607320618320\
601813254535$$

is largest, smaller than $2^{256} -1$

Comment: Awesome, would you be kind to provide $F_{369}$?

Comment: @goodvibration Wolfram alpha will compute this for you.  See, this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci%28370%29), for example.